# Javascript detection of browser focus/visibility when mac screenshot tool is used

Tags: javascript

I'm building a game and I use the keypress events to detect certain keys being used. Basically updating a boolean flag via addEventListener for keydown and keyup. Works great.

However, I use the "shift" key for a certain powerup in the game. And when users try and take screen recordings via Mac screenshot tool (CTRL+SHIFT+4 or CTRL+SHIFT+5) the shift key causes the power up to get triggered.

It's a mild annoyance, but I've been trying to detect it when this happens via
tracking `document.visibilityState` and `document.hasFocus()`. But neither of them change when the user presses this keyboard combination of Mac.

Is there a way to detect this via Javascript so I can clear the keyup event for the Shift input when it happens?

Comment: Long shot, but did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @ChrisPatty unfortunately I don't think I did...I think I just advised starting the screenshot outside of the window and then refocus the window after recording has started